# Numeric Overflow Wrap in C#

Tags: c#

I need to do a sort of clamp in C#.
When a number hit the maximum it returns to zero, and when it hit the minimum it go backward the maximum.
I need to do this because I want to tile a texture.

Comment: Can we have some code you are working on? It can be useful to determine how to achieve that in the best way. Anyway... you could keep those clamping numbers into private members and use a property to modify them so that you can also check if they reached their maximum and eventually set them back to 0.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: This is my problem: http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/3048/catturakaq.png

Comment: @GiulioZausa That doesn't describe your problem at all (in terms relevant to this question).

Comment: Sorry, when I get the coordinates of the texture using Clamp, I repeat only the last pixel and not the whole texture, so I don't need a Clamp but a Wrap. DirectX can do this, but I need to do it with GDI+.

Comment: OK Solved after hours of search i found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapping_(graphics)
implemented:
`val = val - (float)Math.Round((val - min) / (max - min)) * (max - min);
            if (val < 0)
                val = val + max - min;
            return val;
`
Thanks anyway to all and sorry if I have wasted your time.

Comment: @GiulioZausa: Then post it as answer, maybe it's helpful for someone else in the future. You can even accept it if you want.

Answer (score 7):

What you need is the Modulus operator, (slightly adjusted to handle negative numbers the way you want).

```
public static int Modulas(int input, int divisor)
{
    return (input % divisor + divisor) % divisor;
}
```

Comment: Works only if input > -divisor.

Comment: @MattBurland Yeah, that is a common case you can made.  Modified to cover the general case.

Comment: Also worth noting, this will wrap from `0` to `divisor-1`. So your max value will be one less than the divisor.

Comment: @MattBurland It depends on whether the max value is an inclusive or exclusive bounds.  The OP describes it as: "when it hits the max value" as opposed to "when it exceeds the max value", implying it's exclusive.  In either case, adding 1 tot he divisor is certainly an option, if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought it was worth noting in case somebody else is looking at it and isn't clear of whether the limit is inclusive or exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Modulo is your friend:

```
myVal = (myVal++) % (maxValue+1);
```

For example, if you max value is 4 then:

```
0 % 5 = 0
1 % 5 = 1
2 % 5 = 2
3 % 5 = 3
4 % 5 = 4
5 % 5 = 0
6 % 5 = 1
....
```

Comment: This works for adding values, but not for subtracting.  If you go below 0 you don't wrap to the top.

Comment: I think you'll find that to work properly this expression needs to be: myVal = (++myVal) % (maxValue+1);

Answer (score 2):

Where exactly did you have problems?

It's seems to be pretty straight-forward:

```
int number = 4; int maxNum = 20; int minNum = 5;
number = number > maxNum ? 0 : number < minNum ? maxNum : number;
// 20
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/T3qLWj)

Comment: That only works if you're incrementing/decrimenting the value by one each time.  If you are above the max by 5 then you'll end up at 0, not at 5, which is what is usually expected of "wrapping" semantics.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a simple Clamp, I need a sort of "return" like a tape counter: when the number is major than the maximum it returns to zero

Comment: @GiulioZausa: Maybe i'm simply not familiar with a _clamp_. Note that i've edited my answer to return 0 if the value is greater the max-value.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok, Found the solution**

```
private float Wrap(float val, float min, float max)
    {
        val = val - (float)Math.Round((val - min) / (max - min)) * (max - min);
        if (val < 0)
            val = val + max - min;
        return val;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private const Int32 c_ClampMaximum = X;

private Int32 m_Clamp;

public Int32 Clamp
{
    get { return m_Clamp; }
    set
    {
        if (value >= c_ClampMaximum)
        {
            m_Clamp = 0;

            while (value > c_ClampMaximum)
               value -= c_ClampMaximum;
        }

        m_Clamp = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't wrap properly if you add more than one to the previous value; max+5 should be 5, not 0.  2) you don't handle going below 0 at all.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm fixing it!

Comment: 1) you're still setting the max to zero before you even hit the while loop, and that'll mess you up.  Both that and the `if` should just go away.  2) Your `while` should have `>=` not `>` for it to be zero indexed. 3) You have basically implemented an inefficient equivalent of modulus `%`.  The `%` operator will be shorter, clearer, and run faster. 4) You still aren't handling negative numbers at all.